# Celery get() works in python shell but not in Django view

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I want to check basic Celery functionality inside [official demo Celery project for django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) with [code available here](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django/).

My modification is the demoapp/views.py (and of course urls.py to point to this view):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from demoapp.tasks import add, mul, xsum


def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Your output is: %s" % mul.delay(22,4).get(timeout=1) )
```

which always gives timeout error, though the terminal of running Celery worker shows that task was received and displays correct return value.

However, if I start python shell `python ./manage.py shell` and then run

```
from demoapp.tasks import add, mul, xsum
mul.delay(22,4).get(timeout=1)
```

I immediately get the expected result. What may be the problem?

Rabbitmq server is running, I use Celery 4.2.1, django 2.0.6.

demoapp/tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@shared_task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@shared_task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

proj/celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

proj/settings.py

```
...
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///results.sqlite'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
...
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Even as a test, it seems to be completely missing the point of celery.

Comment: This is just to check that django and celery work together. Real applications would of course be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing result backend as stated at [the bottom of this page](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).